# Running JPad, but an exception occurred

Tags: jpad

I download JPad from http://jpad.io/download and setup the software.
When started JPad, but an exception occurred. The program cannot be started, the following is the startup log

```
jpadgui.bat
 02, 2024 2:37:30  com.timestored.docs.OpenDocumentsModel addDocument
Ϣ: addDocument: new 1
 02, 2024 2:37:30  io.jpad.JPadLauncher launch
Ϣ: Starting JPadLauncher  launch() ###################################
 02, 2024 2:37:30  io.jpad.JPadFrame <init>
Ϣ: Starting JPadFrame Constructor
 02, 2024 2:37:31  com.timestored.swingxx.FileTreePanel refreshGui
Ϣ: FileTreePanel refreshGui
 02, 2024 2:37:31  com.timestored.swingxx.FileTreePanel setRoot
Ϣ: root changing
 02, 2024 2:37:31  com.timestored.swingxx.FileTreePanel refreshGui
Ϣ: FileTreePanel refreshGui
 02, 2024 2:37:31  com.timestored.misc.ErrorReporter$UncaughtErrorReporter uncaughtException
: uncaught error
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1312)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1287)
        at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(SwingUtilities.java:1348)
        at io.jpad.JPadLauncher.main(JPadLauncher.java:81)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is already a dockable registered with name ļ
        at bibliothek.gui.DockFrontend.addDockable(DockFrontend.java:567)
        at io.jpad.JPadFrame.createDockable(JPadFrame.java:432)
        at io.jpad.JPadFrame.addRenderer(JPadFrame.java:418)
        at io.jpad.JPadFrame.<init>(JPadFrame.java:199)
        at io.jpad.JPadLauncher.launch(JPadLauncher.java:110)
        at io.jpad.JPadLauncher.access$200(JPadLauncher.java:31)
        at io.jpad.JPadLauncher$2.run(JPadLauncher.java:83)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:749)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:719)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

What is the problem and how to solve it